# Can one use CSS :nth-child (or similar) to select batches of elements in HTML, e.g every other 4 nodes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Bit of background: I'm trying to achieve a layout where the elements flow left-to-right on one row, then right-to-left on the next row, and so on..
I've mocked up something in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwGWpM), have a look here (it explains it better than I can!)

I've achieved the above example using `nth-child` but it's 'hardcoded', e.g.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  ...
  <li>16</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { float: left; }

li:nth-child(5),
li:nth-child(6),
li:nth-child(7),
li:nth-child(8) {
  float: right;
}
```

Now, this works but it's obviously limited to a specific number of elements (how many I put in the CSS!). I know I can do `:nth-child(4n)` to get every fourth element, but I want to be able to select that *and* the next 4. It's almost like `nth-child(odd)`, but for groups of 4 elements.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? I have looked at tweaking Quantity Queries (http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) but that doesn't seem quite what I'm after...

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you're looking for a css answer for this, but personally I would use jQuery to add a class of `left` or `right` to the li's and float those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a group of `nth-child` selectors like in the below snippet to select a repeating group of elements based on a pattern.

One thing to note is that selecting every 4th element and the next 4 after it is equivalent to selecting all elements after the 4th element and hence I have restricted the sample to just the next 2 elements.

---

**Explanation of the selector (selects 4th, 5th, 8th, 9th elements and so on):**

- `nth-child(4n+4)` - selects 4th (4*0 + 4), 8th (4*1 + 4), 12th (4*2  +4) elements
- `nth-child(4n+5)` - selects 5th (4*0 + 5), 9th (4*1 + 5), 13th (4*2 + 5) elements.

As you can see from the explanation, the series starts from the 4th element and repeats from then on. If your need is to start with the series from the 1st element (say 1st, 2nd, 5th, 6th etc) then you could use the selector group as `div:nth-child(4n+1), div:nth-child(4n+2)`.

```css
div:nth-child(4n+4), div:nth-child(4n+5){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
```

---

**Explanation of the selector (selects 4th, 5th, 12th, 13th elements and so on):**

- `nth-child(8n+4)` - selects 4th (8*0 + 4), 12th (8*1 + 4), 20th (8*2  +4) elements
- `nth-child(8n+5)` - selects 5th (8*0 + 5), 13th (8*1 + 5), 21th (8*2 + 5) elements.

As you can see from the explanation, the series starts from the 4th element and repeats from then on. If your need is to start with the series from the 1st element (say 1st, 2nd, 5th, 6th etc) then you could use the selector group as `div:nth-child(4n+1), div:nth-child(4n+2)`.

```css
div:nth-child(8n+4), div:nth-child(8n+5){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
<div>21</div>
<div>22</div>
<div>23</div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I was after, but  I need it to skip every other row, e.g. 4th, 12th, (missing out 8th). If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah - if I use `:nth-child(8n+5), :nth-child(8n+6)` I get what I wanted! Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @Paul: Ah ok, good that you were able to work it out :) I will update that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that, if you wanna select the childs 5,6,7,8 out of 16, you can use

```
:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(n+9)
```

Maybe you find out for yourself, what that does ;)

Comment: Cool, thanks. The only problem with that is that I don't know the total number of children..But, that's a good trick for a fixed size list, thanks!